# Hibernate: QuerySyntaxException: An AnyType attribute cannot be join fetched

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to execute an hql query in Hibernate to implement a join among some tables but I got the exception below. Any ideas how can I solve this? 
Actually I want to implement the query below in HQL style:

```
select * from documentlink dl
        left join digitalfile df on df.iddigitalfile = dl.ParentId and dl.entity = 261
        where (dl.entity = 5 and dl.parentId = 39845) OR (df.entity = 5 and df.parentId = 39845);
```

DocumentLink.java:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DigitalFileCategory")
private DigitalFileCategory digitalFileCategory;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "DocumentMetaData")
private DocumentMetaData documentMetaData;

@Column(name = "ParentId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer parentId;

@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "Entity"), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "integer", metaType = "integer", metaValues = {
    @MetaValue(value = "1", targetEntity = Raetsrelation.class), @MetaValue(value = "5", targetEntity = Claim.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "6", targetEntity = Policy.class), @MetaValue(value = "7", targetEntity = Quotation.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "8", targetEntity = Declaration.class), @MetaValue(value = "29", targetEntity = Claimsecurity.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "30", targetEntity = Survey.class), @MetaValue(value = "33", targetEntity = Incidentlocation.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "41", targetEntity = Endorsement.class), @MetaValue(value = "46", targetEntity = Invoice.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "79", targetEntity = BlueCard.class), @MetaValue(value = "88", targetEntity = MajorClaimNotice.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "91", targetEntity = DeficiencyEvent.class), @MetaValue(value = "97", targetEntity = RiskAssessment.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "109", targetEntity = PolicyCancellation.class), @MetaValue(value = "158", targetEntity = Broker.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "195", targetEntity = Supplier.class), @MetaValue(value = "196", targetEntity = Sla.class),
    @MetaValue(value = "261", targetEntity = DigitalFile.class), @MetaValue(value = "268", targetEntity = DocumentEmail.class)
})
@JoinColumn(name = "ParentId")
private Object parentEntityObject;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Entity", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Entity entity;

//so on
```

Query:

```
final TypedQuery<DocumentLink> query1 = entityManager
    .createQuery("select distinct dl " +
                "from DocumentLink as dl, DigitalFile as df " +
                "where (df.iddigitalfile = 174694) and " +
                "((dl.entity.identity = :entityId and dl.parentId = :parentId) or (df.entity.identity = :entityId and df.parentId = :parentId)) "
        ,DocumentLink.class);
query1.setParameter("entityId", baseInstance.getEntityId());
query1.setParameter("parentId", baseInstance.getId());
List<DocumentLink> documentLinks1 = query1.getResultList();
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: An AnyType attribute cannot be join fetched [select distinct dl from com.raetsmarine.raetsbase3.domain.DocumentLink as dl join fetch dl.documentMetaData as dmd join fetch dmd.publishedBy join fetch dmd.documentLinkSet as dmddl join fetch dmd.documentType as dt left join fetch dl.parentEntityObject as peo with (peo.parentId=261) where (dl.entity.identity = 261 and dl.parentId= :parentId) or (dl.entity.identity = :entityId and dl.parentId= :parentId) ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:342)
    ... 171 more
```

Comment: Try mapping the meta column in the same way as you have the `parentId` and then simply query `select from DocumentLink dl where dl.parentId = :parentId and dl.entityId = :entityId`. The `dl.entity.identity` part is the problem, even though I don't see entity attribute in your code.

Comment: I just edited my post. It's already there. 
The problem is with the digitalFile "casting" but I cannot investigate it.

Comment: entity should imho be `Integer` not `Entity`.

Comment: This is the reason that I use entity.identity! Should be Entity coz of other reasons.

Comment: Hm, actually the best way would probably be to have also the reverse association mapped (from DigitalFile to DocumentLink) and then build the query as `select df.documentlink from DigitalFile df where df.iddigitalfile = 12345 and whatever other filtering you need`, This way, Hibernate should handle the left join without issues.

Comment: If you need filtering on document link as well, it is possible to do the join this way `select dl from DigitalFile df LEFT JOIN df.documentlink dl WHERE etc.`

Comment: @Wabi I need a left join on document link coz DigitalFile contains a set of Document Links